# Can i write two separate pojo classes one for validation and another for hibernate mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, spring-mvc

If yes, how to map them. I am using jsr bean validation and hibernate mapping annotations.

Comment: What is your use case? Maybe simply create two pojos one that is mapped using hibernate and one that is validated (e.g. with hibernate-validator or the `@Valid` annotation in springs controller) and then copied to your first pojo (look for `BeanUtils`)?

Comment: I agreee @gregor. Did you mean you want to map two classes to one table? for validation and persistence, I don't think you need doing it  this way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this by mapping two classes to one table.
You can just define one class A which map to a table as a PO (Persistent Object), and define another class B which transfer values amgonst View, Controler and Service Layer as a DTO/VO (Data Transfer Object/Value Object) for validation or data transfering. use ***BeanUtils*** to copy properties between PO and DTO.